# Choosing between if() and try-catch

Tags: exception, try-catch, multiple-languages

For example, what should I use when it is necessary to create a column in the table only if such column does not exist?

I can write a code that will check if a column exists doesn't exist, and only then add it, so I can and it without check by wrapping my method in the try-catch (if there is - catch exceptions, and if not - the column will be added)

The result will be the same.

And there are a lot of examples, for example, you can scan files to exist, and only then make a copy, and you can catch exceptions.

Which method is more literate, or the right?

Comment: Generally, exception are for *exceptional* events.

Comment: I have faced the same before but with array size. I could have check every time if I overtake the size of an array using [if()], but when I used try catch, I didn't care any more about the size of array, simply If I overtake the size, catch statement will handle the error and continue doing your code

Comment: An exception is a failure. If you want to learn more you should read the chapter about exceptions in [this book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Oriented_Software_Construction). When  you reach the end of the file, when your table needs another column it's not a failure.

Comment: Also, in some languages exceptions are expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly enough, your question depends on the programming language you are talking about.

In languages such as C, Java, C++, C# ... people prefer the "LBYL" (Look Before You Leap) pattern; whereas languages such as python heavily emphasize "EAFP" (it's Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission).

Meaning: in python, you are using try/catch **a lot** (even the "counting for loop" is implemented as try/catch); whereas in C#, Java, C++ you would prefer doing if/else instead.

And these conventions are really important to follow - most Cx-language programmers simply assume that you don't use try/catch to model control flow. In other words: you should follow that paradigm that the majority of other developers in that language would be using.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a "right" way to go. Either way works so that you achieve your goal no matter what. For clean code however, my (very subjective) view is that exceptions should only be used as that very "literal" thing and indicate that something exceptional (or unexpected) has occured. So in most cases you would simply be overspamming your runtime with exceptions. If however you seek to scan a document and always expect to have a certain number of columns, it might be the right way to go with an exception, as the wrong number of columns would be just that: an exception.